# Roblox for Linux

Tags: linux, roblox

Is there any Roblox version for Ubuntu Linux? I need help and I want to enjoy playing Jailbreak and driving in my SUV and my Buggati!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use [this installer script off of Github](https://github.com/roblox-linux-wrapper/roblox-linux-wrapper)** making sure you run [Wine 6.11](https://www.winehq.org/announce/6.11) or later. Keep in mind this method is completely unsupported, and might also cause an automated account ban for cheating, due to the DLL injection method used by Wine.

There is currently no *native* build of Roblox for linux, however a few independent developers have indicated interest in the Linux environment. We will need to wait and see.

Comment: bonus round; if you have a decent PC and can run it correctly, a Windows 10 VM could in theory work. i personally have gotten bad results, however, because my PC is on par at best, and it lags horribly in my VirtualBox VM

Answer (score 0):

Try installing virtualbox and creating a Windows VM. You could run it on that if your PC is fast.